# C# - Add a pdf in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, canvas

I have a project, where I may display some shapes in Canvas.
In some cases, I don't have shapes, so I would like to use original drawing in pdf format, and insert it inside the Canvas.
Is there a way to such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that comes to my mind is to host a [`WebBrowser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser?view=net-5.0) ActiveX control in your application and then use it to visualize the PDF content. Still, I believe it is far from ideal. There are a lot of WPF component vendors that offer PDF viewers, but choosing between them is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: In fact I read this answer on a similar question (but for JavaScript). For now didn't find any "easier" way...

Comment: If budget and scope allow it, I would definitely try a dedicated component, which is a native WPF control. ActiveX is a legacy framework and it will most likely bring you more harm than help on the long run.

Comment: in fact I was looking for a way to do it without external components. Seems it is just not possible. I will look about WebBrowser option then. Thanks for your help